# Errors when mixing ddply and interval

Tags: r

I've been trying to calculate intervals for individuals and have run into a weird error. Specifically, in this code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)
df<-tibble(dates=mdy(c("2/20/20","2/25/20","3/1/20","3/11/20","3/20/20")),recips=c("x","x","a","a","a"),treatment=c("T","P","T","P","P"),eventtype=c("a","real","y","z","real"))

df%>%mutate(window=interval(start=dates,end=dates+weeks(2)))
ddply(df,.(recips),mutate,window=interval(start=dates,end=dates+weeks(2)))
```

the last line draws an error that the second to last line doesn't draw. Any tips?

Comment: Why do you need `ddply` when `mutate` from `dplyr` is working i.e. `df%>% group_by(recips) %>% mutate(window=interval(start=dates,end=dates+weeks(2)))` works for me

Comment: @akrun I was under the impression that ddply was faster than group_by()%>%mutate(). I'm going to scale this up to a 100M rows, which has been slow with group_by().

Comment: More devel is happening in tidverse.  So, I would guess the tidyverse approach to be optimized.  I could be wrong

Comment: I am kind of curious about the group_by here.  Based on the data showed, you want to get the interval for each 'date'.  So, why you are grouping

Comment: `plyr` has been retired long back. You should use `dplyr` for all the data-manipulation task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue would be the `class` of the output of `interval` which is not in compliance with the `ddply`.  An option is to convert to `character` with `as.character`

```
plyr::ddply(df, c("recips"), plyr::mutate,
  window = as.character(interval(start = dates, end = dates + weeks(2))))
```

-output

```
#     dates recips treatment eventtype                         window
#1 2020-03-01      a         T         y 2020-03-01 UTC--2020-03-15 UTC
#2 2020-03-11      a         P         z 2020-03-11 UTC--2020-03-25 UTC
#3 2020-03-20      a         P      real 2020-03-20 UTC--2020-04-03 UTC
#4 2020-02-20      x         T         a 2020-02-20 UTC--2020-03-05 UTC
#5 2020-02-25      x         P      real 2020-02-25 UTC--2020-03-10 UTC
```

---

Based on the data showed, we are creating the `interval` on each element of 'date'.  So, the `group_by` operation is not needed

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
        mutate(window = interval(start=dates,end=dates+weeks(2)))
```